# Keycloak exports only a single realm (the master)

Tags: keycloak, bitnami

trying to use the keycloak export command

```
standalone.sh -Dkeycloak.migration.action=export -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir -Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/opt/keycloak-export -Dkeycloak.migration.usersExportStrategy=DIFFERENT_FILES -Dkeycloak.migration.usersPerFile=100
```

As U can see `-Dkeycloak.migration.realmName` is not specified so it's expected that all the realms in keycloak will be exported.

interesting logs:

```
10:45:49,873 INFO  [org.keycloak.exportimport.dir.DirExportProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) Exporting into directory /opt/keycloak-export
10:45:56,004 INFO  [org.keycloak.exportimport.dir.DirExportProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) Realm 'master' - data exported
10:45:56,060 INFO  [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) KC-SERVICES0035: Export finished successfully
```

keycloak is running in a Kubernetes cluster, using [bitnami helm chart](https://bitnami.com/stack/keycloak/helm)

Getting access to keycloak bash using `kubectl exec -it kaycloak-pod -- bash`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

add `-c=standalone-ha.xml` to your export command

bitnami uses this config file for the database resource

Note: bitnami keycloak helm uses bitnami keycloak docker image

bitnami standalone.sh command:
https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-keycloak/blob/542a52b98e4f29626140a696062755c8093a9014/16/debian-10/rootfs/opt/bitnami/scripts/keycloak/run.sh#L21

config_file:
https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-keycloak/blob/542a52b98e4f29626140a696062755c8093a9014/16/debian-10/rootfs/opt/bitnami/scripts/keycloak-env.sh#L106